# ASP.NET Core with React.JS the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I’ve created an “ASP.NET Core with React.JS” project with individual Auth.

After I registered a new account and log in, I tried to go to the Fetch Data page, but it does not return data and shows the followings problems in the console :

[image]

[image]

Since it's a new project, and I didn't modify anything yet, what should I do to let it fetch authorized data?

and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can check the network data in broswer, then we can find below msg.

[image]

Then I search this error message, then I found this should be [`.NET 6.0 Known Issues`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#spa-template-issues-with-individual-authentication-when-running-in-development).

You can try the two ways in the doc to fix your issue. I can't fix this issue in my side, but I think this doc should be useful to you.